# Non-Clustered Index on all the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

If is allowed to create 249 Non-Clustered Indexes on a table does it mean its safe to have a Non-Clustered on every column? What would be the effect of that? Or we have to choose only some columns to create a non-clustered index.

IS this:

```
create nonclustered index ix_test(col1, col2, col3)
```

Different from this: ?

```
create nonclustered index ix_test(col1)
create nonclustered index ix_test2(col2)
create nonclustered index ix_test3(col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are good for reads and bad for writes.

When you are only reading data Indexes can help to find the data quicker and make your reads quick.

On the other hand

When you are writing Data (UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT) sql server will have to write data twice once on the SQL Server Pages where the actual data is stored and once for Indexes. which will result in slower writes.

You will have to find that middle ground where your reads do not suffer from not enough helping indexes and your writes not suffer from too many indexes.

The above statement is true for OLTP applications, where data is changing quite frequently but if it is an OLAP/Data warehouse data hardly changes if ever, you can add as many as indexes your reads require to perform better. Hope this helps.

Comment: So that's why unique/guid are good candidate for index because they don't change.

Comment: I think you meant to say guid is a good candidate for clustered index, well its not. An identity value is a much better candidate for a clustered index.

Comment: Unused and redundant indexes waste space in addition to the extra maintenance overhead.  Complicated queries, along with many indexes, can result in longer compile times than necessary and sometimes suboptimal plans too.